# Destroying a shared_ptr member variable in the class destructor using a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to recreate destroying a shared_ptr member variable in the `bar` class destructor using a `thread` which I feel may be the reason for a heap corruption. I personally feel it is strange to use a thread in a destructor, so I want the opinion from SO.

The pointer may outlive the application , so using `detach` is more desirable. The destructor is not called if `detach` used, however it works if `join`.

1) Is it wrong to reset a smart pointer this way?

2) Why the destructor is not called when `std::thread::detach()` was used ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
    public:
    foo(){longcomputation();}
    void longcomputation() 
    { 
        std::cout<<" long computation called \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 
    }
};

class bar
{
    public:
    bar(): foo_(std::make_shared<foo>()) {}
    ~bar() 
    {
        std::thread([foo = std::move(foo_)] () mutable
        {
          foo.reset();
          std::cout<<" bar dctor called \n";
        }).detach();  // ==========> works with join however
    }
    private:
    std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_;
};



int main()
{
    bar bar1;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::cout << "Exiting\n";
}
```

Comment: The code looks a little horrifying. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @RichardHodges: yep, just debugging a sample code from a project. Will the reset be skipped when detach is used?

Comment: What's the reason to create a thread in the *destructor*? Also since you create the thread in the `bar` destructor it might not even get the change to run since the `bar` object will be destructed as part of the `main` function returning and the process as a whole will exit.

Comment: I don't even see the point of doing a manual `reset` in the destructor (least of all in a thread which does nothing else). When the `bar` object is destructed so will the shared pointer `foo_` also be, which will in effect be equivalent to your reset call.

Comment: you are doing the long computation in the constructor of the object.  so the thread is called only after the function return from there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Nice one +1, frankly I have seen this in an open source project code, which still buggy and I myself feel using thread in destructor is very strange. Hope SO may shed some light on this one.

Comment: It might make sense in the context of the project you found it in, but not in the context of your MCVE. But I honestly don't believe it makes more sense even *with* the context of the full project.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I feel so too and I want to alert in Git regarding this but need more inputs if its there.

Comment: @ArkadyGodlin: the longcompu ( 1 sec) should execute before main ( 3sec) exits

Comment: The sleeps are all a red herring. All the interesting stuff happens at the closing brace of `main`, after sleep calls returned. At that point, `bar1` goes out of scope and its destructor is called. The destructor creates a detached thread and returns - but before that thread has a chance to run, `main` exits and the whole process terminates.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a bad way to handle threads and smart pointers and though I am not some C++ Guru, I would say this is a bad way to code in C++ overall (there will almost surely be issues of readability maintainability etc.).

Coming to the destructor, before the detached thread could be scheduled, the destructor exits, destroying the `foo_` object and hence, `std::move(foo_)` fails. And when you use `join()` instead of `detach()`, you are making the destructor wait for the thread, which is why it works. It would also work if we build a sleep in the destructor after detaching the thread:

```
~bar()
{
    std::thread([foo = std::move(foo_)] () mutable
    {
      foo.reset();
      std::cout<<" bar dctor called \n";
    }).detach();  // ==========> works with join however
    // this works too
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```